# I have a couple of answers upvoted

Tags: support, up-votes, daily-reputation-limit

What happens to those answers that have been upvoted but have exceeded my maximum points of 200 very early on within a 24 hour day? Do they get adjusted when the 24 hours have lapsed i.e. carry it over to the next day with the adjusted upvotes, some of them have 3 and a blank, others are accepted but no more...so is there any real point to me hanging around on SO if I can answer questions but get no more upvotes?

Can anyone answer this for me as the FAQ seems a bit vague in that respect?

Thanks,
Best regards,
Tom.

Comment: Sure there's a point hanging around - you can give people helpful answers to their questions!

Comment: Or help editing questions, like if you think a title could be improved... ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reputation from upvotes after you hit the reputation cap is lost. You don't get the reputation for them.

See [this thread](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work-on-stack-overflow) for all of the parts of the reputation system.

---

One of the reasons you might stick around is that if your answer is accepted as the answer to the question, you still get the 15 reputation from it, even after the reputation cap.

Comment: @Chacha102: I did not know about this if the question is accepted and maxed the rep points for the day, it will still get points...

Comment: The upvotes aren't *lost* -- they still fulfill their primary purpose, which is ordering good answers on top. They also still count towards things like the "Good Question" badge. They just don't generate rep. Also @tommieb75: The 15 points for having an answer accepted are exempt from the rep cap; you'll always get them.

Comment: @balpha I reworded that.

Answer (score 1):

There is no adjustment made, you just simply don't get the rep added from upvotes that would take you past 200.  You'll see that in your recent activity by some positive value that is not a factor of 10 (or labeled Bty for bounty awarded).  That'll be the balance of the rep you'll earn that day.

And the point isn't to bank rep, it's to provide useful input to the community.  So sure there's a point in hanging around!!

Comment: I realize that yes its good to hang around - bloody addictive I must say :) Sure I love helping..but it's nice to see the rep increase...how the hell did Jon Skeet do it...that seeing his rep makes me want to be a better guy...it can be competitive if you know what I mean despite my passion and addiction to SO... :)

Comment: Well, Jon literally wrote the book on the subject for one.  Plus, bounty awards and accepted answers aren't subject to the rep cap.